# does not template render, url expression regex

Tags: regex, django, url

[image: Imagem error look here]
**Template-html**

```
  <p>
   <a href="{% url 'courses:enrollment' courses.slug % }" class="pure-buttonprimary-button">Inscreva-se</a>
   </p>
```

**URLS.py**

```
    urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', index, name = 'index'),
    #url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', details, name = 'details'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w_-]+)/$', details, name = 'details'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w_-]+)/inscricao/$', enrollment, name = 'enrollment'),

]
```

Url does not find the path specified.

Comment: Please take the effort and make your question look nice. Also please state what exactly your question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space between the `%` and `}` at the end of the tag.

```
{% url 'courses:enrollment' courses.slug % }
                                          ^
```

Change it to

```
{% url 'courses:enrollment' courses.slug %}
```

Since you are using the namespace `courses` in your tag `courses:enrollment`, you should set `app_name` in your `courses/urls.py` file.

```
app_name = 'courses'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
```

Comment: OMG...Many thanks for the help, not how I did not see it

Answer (score 0):

You are using the word "courses" in your URL reversal, even though it was never defined. Try using just this: `{% url 'enrollment' courses.slug % }`